# Duvida com uso de listas em python

Tags: python, lista

Queria fazer um programa para sortear 2 times de 10 jogadores cada e que não repetisse nenhum dos jogadores nos times. Só consegui fazer isso até agora porém os jogadores se repetem.

```
import random

top1 = str(input("Player 1: "))
top2 = str(input("Player 2: "))
jg1 = str(input("Player 3: "))
jg2 = str(input("Player 4: "))
mid1 = str(input("Player 5: "))
mid2 = str(input("Player 6: "))
adc1 = str(input("Player 7: "))
adc2 = str(input("Player 8: "))
sup1 = str(input("Player 9: "))
sup2 = str(input("Player 10: "))

times = [top1, top2, jg1, jg2, mid1, mid2, adc1, adc2, sup1, sup2]
random.shuffle(times)

time1 = random.sample(times, 5)
time2 = random.sample(times, 5)
print("O primeiro time é {}".format(time1))
print("O Segundo time é {}".format(time2))
```

Comment: Se sorteou a ordem da lista `times`, por que não pega os 5 primeiros para um time e o restante para o outro time?

Comment: a minha ideia era de o programa já separar os 2 times direto, para facilitar o usuário

Comment: Concordo com o @Woss, como a lista `times` for embaralhada é só fazer `time1, time2 = times[:5], times[5:]` que os times serão formados aleatoriamente e sem duplicação.

Answer (score 0):

A Solução comentada do Woss é uma boa saida para o seu problema, porem pode acontecer de entrar jg1 e jg2 no mesmo grupo do time caso isso não seja um problema a solução de pegando os 5 primeiros e depois os 5 ultimos já é resolve o problema, mas caso precise que  apenas 1 pessoa do mesmo tipo permaneça no time então não vai atender, oque é possivel de fazer é atribuir aleatoriamente os valores em pares do mesmo grupo assim cada time tem 1 respectivo membro correto.

Exemplo de código com suas saidas

```
import random

top1 =  "t1"
top2 =  "t2"
jg1 =   "j1"
jg2 =   "j2"
mid1 =  "m1"
mid2 =  "m2"
adc1 =  "a1"
adc2 =  "a2"
sup1 =  "s1"
sup2 =  "s2"

times = [top1, top2, jg1, jg2, mid1, mid2, adc1, adc2, sup1, sup2]
random.shuffle(times)

time1 = times[:5]
time2 = times[5:10]
print("O primeiro time é {}".format(time1))
print("O Segundo time é {}".format(time2))
#Saida
# O primeiro time é ['s1', 'a1', 't2', 'a2', 't1']
# O Segundo time é ['m2', 'j2', 'm1', 'j1', 's2']


top = [top1,top2]
jg = [jg1,jg2]
mid = [mid1,mid2]
adc = [adc1,adc2]
sup = [sup1,sup2]

time_1 = []
time_2 = []
for item in [top,jg,mid,sup]:
  roll = random.randint(0,1)
  
  time_1.append(item[roll])
  time_2.append(item[(roll+1 if roll == 0 else roll-1)])

print(time_1,  "Time 1")
print(time_2,  "Time 2")
#Saida
# ['t1', 'j2', 'm2', 's2'] Time 1
# ['t2', 'j1', 'm1', 's1'] Time 2
```